# View Composer not working Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have App\Http\NotificationComposer.php:

```
namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\View\View;

class NotificationComposer
{
    public $notifications;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->notifications = json_decode(\Auth::user()->notifications, true);
    }
    public function compose (View $view)
    {
        dd($this->notifications);
        $view->with('notifications');
    }
}
```

I also have a App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider.php:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer(
            'app',
            'App\Http\ViewComposers\NotificationComposer'
            );
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And in my config\app.php:

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider::class,
    ...
    ],
];
```

I believe I have set up the view composer correctly, however everytime layouts\app.blade.php is loaded (the default bootstrap bar in laravel) it isn't rendering any notifications, even though there are some in the database, I have attempted to dd them as you can see in the view composer.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening or what I haven't done properly?

Thanks,

Comment: So, you shouldn't register new service providers in the `aliases` array in config/app.php, it should be above that with the rest of the service providers. Also, `app` may be a reserved View Composer name, but I don't know.

Comment: Not sure what's going on here, but keep in mind the view composer only triggers for names of views that are "made" via `View::make` or `Response::view`. If you extend the `app` view from a `myview` then your composer needs to be registered for `myview`

Comment: How do i register a view if i didnt make it with view::make?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've made a workaround instead. This wasn't registering for some reason so I place this inside of the  AppServiceProivder.php

```
view()->composer(
        'layouts.app', function ($view){
            $view->with('notifications', json_decode(\Auth::user()->notifications, true));
        });
```

It's not as clean but for something this small, I guess it's ok.